# MySQL ordering by a particular column value with a secondary order by another column's date

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns in it:

```
status
scheduled_start
```

I would like to sort it to show rows with the status set to "Needs Attention" first, but I want a secondary sort by scheduled_start in ASC order.

Doing:

```
SELECT `tickets`.* FROM `tickets` ORDER BY CASE status WHEN 'Needs Attention' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AND scheduled_start ASC
```

Will produce the rows sorted by status = Needs Attention, but the secondary sort by scheduled start is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unnecessary "AND" in the ORDER BY clause. Try replacing it with a comma instead:

```
SELECT `tickets`.* 
FROM `tickets` 
ORDER BY 
   CASE status WHEN 'Needs Attention' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
   scheduled_start ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT `tickets`.* FROM `tickets` ORDER BY CASE WHEN `status` = 'Needs Attention' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, scheduled_start ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Order by clause is not a condition, it is a list of fields and expressions you want to sort on, so separate them by commas, not an and:

```
.... order by expression1, field1
```